# Mockito 'when' with JPA Repository with ignoreCase finder method

Tags: java, regex, unit-testing, jpa, mockito

I am trying to mock my user repository which is case insensitive... and mockito returns an object where it shouldn't...

```
    Pattern adminPattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("admin"), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Pattern admin2Pattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("admin2"), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    Mockito.when(userRepo.findByUserNameIgnoreCase(Mockito.matches(adminPattern))).thenReturn(user1);
    Mockito.when(userRepo.findByUserNameIgnoreCase(Mockito.matches(admin2Pattern))).thenReturn(user2);

    Assert.isTrue(adminPattern.matcher("admin").matches(), "admin should match");
    Assert.isTrue(adminPattern.matcher("adMIN").matches(), "adMIN should match");
    Assert.isTrue(admin2Pattern.matcher("admin2").matches(), "admin2 should  match");
    Assert.isTrue(admin2Pattern.matcher("adMIN2").matches(), "adMIN2 should  match");

    Assert.isTrue(!adminPattern.matcher("admin3").matches(), "admin3 should not match");
    Assert.isTrue(!admin2Pattern.matcher("adMIN").matches(), "adMIN should not match");
    Assert.isTrue(!admin2Pattern.matcher("adMIN3").matches(), "adMIN3 should not match");

    Assert.isTrue(userRepo.findByUserNameIgnoreCase("admin").equals(user1), "Admin must be found");
    Assert.isTrue(userRepo.findByUserNameIgnoreCase("adMIN").equals(user1), "Admin must be found");
    Assert.isNull(userRepo.findByUserNameIgnoreCase("anything"), "anything must not be found");

    Assert.isNull(userRepo.findByUserNameIgnoreCase("admin3"), "Admin3 must not be found");
```

The last line goes wrong... Mockito returns user1 instead of nothing.
It seems to me that the 'matches' is in reality a 'startsWith' which is kind of surprising to me...
Or my regex Pattern matcher is wrong... Or I am missing something else really obvious (to others :-))

Thanks a lot for some ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at at `org.mockito.internal.matchers.Matches` class,
you'll notice that it calls `find`, not `matches` on the regex pattern matcher.

```
@Override
public boolean matches(Object actual) {
    return (actual instanceof String) && pattern.matcher((String) actual).find();
}
```

The difference is:

- `find` looks for the occurence of the pattern in the input string
- `matches` attempts to match the entire input against the pattern.

To force matching of entire input, you can modify your pattern slightly: `"^admin$"`

Comment: If I also remove my 'Pattern.quote' it works as expected, thanks a lot!